# Azure Devops + Coverlet + SonarQube shows 0%

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, sonarqube, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

Good morning,

Sorry to bother you, I have a problem and I have no leads.

I have a pipeline on Azure DevOps where I use coverlet to generate a code coverage report when I use the command "dotnet test".

[image]

Indeed, the report is well generated.

[image]

At first, in the "Prepare analysis on SonarQube" step, I set the variable "sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="$(Agent.TempDirectory)/coverage.opencover.xml".

[image]

And yet the end in my SonarQube there is 0% code coverage... I don't know what to do or any leads...

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Alex Planchon Did you check out below steps? please let me know if there is any question.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT I just posted my "solution", it is now working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a lot of things to finally managed to get the coverage working but I think that the problem was the "ProjectGUID" missing in each .csproj of my solution making the projects ignored by SonarQube scanner.

I also upgraded from SonarQube 6.2 to 8.1 at the same time which may have solved the problem.

My steps remained unchanged to make this work.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce above issue. And it is hard to troubleshoot since you did not share your configuration for **dotnet test task** or **sonarqube prepare task**.

I created a test project and the coverage was successfully published to my sonarqube server. You can refer to below my steps.

1, create sonarqube server and configure my projectName and projectKey (I use azure sonarqube container instance, check [here](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/sonarqube/) for details).

2, configure [sonarqube service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-service-connection) in azure devops.

3, create build pipeline. I use yaml pipeline.

In **Prepare Analysis Configuration task**, I choose to **Use standalone scanner**, and **Mode** is **Manually provide configure**. And I set variable `sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="$(Agent.TempDirectory)/coverage.opencover.xml"`.

Below screenshot is the task's setting in classic ui view.

[image]

In my **dotnet test task** I set the arguments as below, and specifically output the coverage result to `$(Agent.TempDirectory)/` folder.

`arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=$(Agent.TempDirectory)/ /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover'`

> Below is the full content of my azure-pipelines.yml file.

```
trigger: none

jobs:
- job: 'Tests'
  pool: 
    vmImage: windows-latest

  variables:
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  continueOnError: true

  steps:     
  - task: SonarQubePrepare@4
    displayName: 'Prepare analysis on SonarQube'
    inputs:
       SonarQube: sonarlevi
       scannerMode: CLI
       configMode: manual
       cliProjectKey: myproject2
       cliProjectName: myproject2
       extraProperties: |
          sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="$(Agent.TempDirectory)/coverage.opencover.xml"


  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: '**\*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: custom
      custom: tool
      arguments: install --tool-path . dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool 
    displayName: Install ReportGenerator tool

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Test .NET
    inputs:
      command: test
      projects: '**\*Test*.csproj'
      publishTestResults: false
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=$(Agent.TempDirectory)/ /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover'
    condition: succeededOrFailed()


  - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@4

    displayName: 'Run Code Analysis'

  - task: SonarQubePublish@4

    displayName: 'Publish Quality Gate Result'
```

Comment: this was detailed and straight forward